# Who can help me to create a *.bbx file?

Tags: biblatex

I was trying to find a suitable bbx style, but found none. So I decided to make my own. Then I realized that all the `\DeclareBibliographyDriver`, `\usebibmacro` and so on is too complicated for me, I simply don’t understand it, even not while reading the manuals.
So the only thing I can do is to try and then see how it looks like, so I thought that maybe one of you experts could help me. :)
I already found the uni-wtal-lin style which is helpful, but also I want some elements of the authoryear-icomp standard.

```
\documentclass[%
11pt,
a4paper,
%parskip-,
%titlepage,
onepage,
BCOR5mm,
bibliography=totoc,
footsepline,
bookmarksopen=true,
pdfusetitle]{scrreprt}
…
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
maxbibnames=4,
maxcitenames=2,
% Pfad: /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/
style=authoryear-icomp, %uni-wtal-lin // authoryear-icomp
babel=other,
%hyperref=true,
useprefix=true,
url=false,
isbn=false
]{biblatex}
%Anpassungen linguistische Literaturangaben
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon~} % Doppelpunkt zwischen Jahr und Seite: (Meier 1999:~S. 23)
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} %einleitendes S. weg
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon~} %doppelpunkt statt punkt in literaturliste
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
andothers = {{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
}
```

I want the output to look like this:

[book]
Name, Paul (2000): *Title.* Place: Publisher (= Series; Bd. 5).

[inbook]
Name, Paul (2000): *Title.* In: Mayer, Peter/Hans Wurst (Hrsg.): *Book title.* Place: Publisher (= Series; Bd. 5), S. 123–456.

[article]
Name, Paul (2000): *Title.* In: *Journal title* 19/2000, S. 123–456.

Names are in `\textsc{}` And with the same author, I want the second line marked with – and indented a bit :)

Anyone who can help me with this?
Thanks! :)

PS: I tried to make it for book, this is how it looks like (just copy and paste from uni-wtal-lin for testing), anyway, it does’t work:

```
%% requires authoryear
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear-icomp}

%% Book
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
\newblock
  \newunit\newblock
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
\iffieldundef{series}
{}
{\printtext[parens]{%
\iffieldundef{number}
{}
{=\addhpthinspace}%
\printfield{series}%
\setunit*{\addsemicolon\addspace{}Bd.~}%
\printfield{number}%
}}\newunit}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply patch `authoryear` style to modify only the relevant lines in macros, drivers, &c. The `xpatch` package is tailored for that.

Comment: [Crossposted on TeXWelt](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7734/hilfe-bei-bbx-datei)

Comment: Unfortunately your requests are not all that clear. What do you want to happen to multiple authors (name order, name delimiters, "and", commas, etc.). Are people's name other than the author's to be set in small caps as well? It is generally preferred to ask one question at a time. In your case that means you have to identify the particular things you want to change, find out if they have been asked before and answered satisfyingly and, if not, ask a new specific question with a nice short and concise MWE. Be sure to make available all the information, so we can deal with corner cases properly